# Get minutes from a time field in a CakePHP form?

Tags: forms, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm using CakePHP to build a mixed martial arts (MMA) website. I have a form to add matches, and one of the fields is for rounds length, which is in minutes, and which I'm storing in my database as a `TIME` value.

In my form, I only want the minutes portion of the value editable. I've tried creating a field with the name `Match.rounds_length` and setting the type to `number`, but can't get it to populate with the `minutes` value.

Here's what I have currently:

```
$this->Form->input('Match.rounds_length' => array('type' => 'time'));
```

I did find this page in the CakePHP online documentation: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#field-naming-conventions. But I can't seem to get it to work in my setup.

Could someone familiar with CakePHP tell me how to create just an open text field that the user can specify the number of minutes a round should last that would then be saved as a time value in my database, and populated properly in my edit form?

Comment: Can you explain with some dummy details, what kind of actual output it should looks like?

Comment: Well if the value in the database is 00:05:00, then I'd like the text box to just display '05'.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following. And it worked.

```
echo date('i', strtotime('00:05:00'));
```

[date() format specifiers list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) will help you to achieve the same as you mentioned in your question.

Kindly ask if it not worked for you.

Comment: I'm not sure that will save properly in the database with CakePHP's `save()` method though.